# "Internal error while using the pattern" while passing email validation regex to Zend_Validate_Regex

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-form, email-validation

I'm building a form in Zend Forms and get the following error while trying to add email validation regex:

> Internal error while using the pattern

The code is:

```php
$email->setLabel('Email:')
      ->setRequired()
      ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Regex('/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$/i'))
      ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array(3, 255)))
      ->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_StripTags())
      ->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_StringTrim());
```

This regex should validate correct email address and it works in other places (e.g. in JS).

I tried to remove `i` option and to replace `\` with `\\` but neither works. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a built in validator for email addresses, just in case you weren't aware: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.email_address

Comment: @TimFountain I know but it's pretty weak… It doesn't even validate Polish emails…

Comment: [check it here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing closing parenthesis (presumably after the final `?`)

Comment: It doesn't :) Throws a `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression` error.